# How to draw time-series chart on time and value by using Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

How to draw time-series chart by using Python?
Since in the data set, time is split as year, and period (which is Month like M1, M2).

I am using matplotlib, but don't know how to split the time.

The codes I wrote to get the data：
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import DataFrame
    data1 = pd.read_csv('CUUR0000SA0.txt', header = None)
    data2 = pd.read_csv('SUUR0000SA0.txt', header = None)
    data = pd.concat([data1, data2])
    data.columns = ["a"]
    data = DataFrame(data)
    print(data.head())

However, the output dataframe has only one column.

Part of the the data set looks like this:

```
+-------------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
|  series id  | year | period |  value  | footnotes |
+-------------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M12   | 234.812 |           |
| CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M11   | 236.151 |           |
| CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M10   | 237.433 |           |
| CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M09   | 238.031 |           |
| CUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M08   | 237.852 |           |
```

The chart should explain the trend of values using a graph according to the time periods. But I don't know how to transfer it into the right format first.

Comment: Hi Sandy, are you using pandas or numpy? You will need to use the datetime package but the answer may be dependent on how your data is structured.

Comment: Oh, I am using pandas data frame to store the above data.

Comment: It is not clear to me from the question exactly what you would like the resulting chart to look like. What have you tried so far? For example does `df.plot()` get what you need? How about `df.sort_values(['year', 'period']).plot(x='period', y='value')`?

Comment: The thing is that I want to show the value trend based on year and period. But I don't know how to convert this one column dataset into dataframe with several columns.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps to get a solution:

1. transform period values into numbers
2. add a column where values are the combination of year and period
3. plot the time series

And this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = {0: {"series id":"CUUR0000SA0", "year":2014, "period":"M12", "value":234.812},
        1: {"series id":"CUUR0000SA0", "year":2014, "period":"M11", "value":236.151},
       2: {"series id":"CUUR0000SA0", "year":2014, "period":"M10", "value":237.433},
       3: {"series id":"CUUR0000SA0", "year":2014, "period":"M09", "value":238.031},
       4: {"series id":"CUUR0000SA0", "year":2014, "period":"M08", "value":237.852},
       }

d = {'M01':1,
     'M02':2,
     'M02':3,
     'M04':4,
     'M05':5,
     'M06':6,
     'M07':7,
     'M08':8,
     'M09':9,
    'M10':10,
    'M11':11,
    'M12':12,}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient="index")
df.period = df.period.map(d)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.year.astype(str) + '/' + df.period.astype(str) + '/01')

df.plot(x='date', y='value')
```

Comment: I realized the the table in text file actually had only one column. That is to say I have to split it into several columns to store in dataframe. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Please, provide an example of your dataframe, otherwise it will be impossible to understand your question.